# "This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging" except no

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, comments, locked-posts

[image: This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging]

If the comments are not eligible for flagging, how did I just flag one?

[Here's a link to the comment I flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234419#comment99419_234419).

The red flag indicates that I flagged the first comment.

The red error happens when upvoting *any comment*.

Comment: Why ever would you flag that on a histo-locked jokes-list?

Comment: @Deduplicator I was mostly just testing.

Comment: Well, my guess is they did not see any need to put additional checks client-side for the special case of locked posts which may not be voted nor flagged on. Any code may be broken, and unused/underused code probably is.

Comment: @Deduplicator But the flag submitted without problems so it apparently passed server-side validation.

Comment: Sooo many useless comments there.

Comment: So the bug is not that you're seeing this message, the bug is that you were able to flag a comment there, right?

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, that's right.

Comment: So you flagged one, didn’t get that message, flagged another on the same post, and did? (And you didn’t accidentally flag something twice?)

Comment: @minitech Flagging works on all the comments, voting does not and causes the error.

Comment: yup; there's a test that used to be there that isn't there any more; I need to check which is right: the message text, or the current checks

Comment: @Marc So… 6 months later… Status report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps comment flags should be disabled on posts with the *historical* lock, but there's no particularly good reason to disable flags on locked posts as a matter of course... Meanwhile, flags have not been disabled on comments below locked posts of any type in a very long time - so making the message accurate is the most important thing here:

[image: Screenshot of comment vote attempt on locked post: Comments on locked posts are not eligible for voting]

That's live now. Details here: [Error message says I can't flag... but yes I can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195527/error-message-says-i-cant-flag-but-yes-i-can/322215#322215)